# How to create a square-shaped plot with same number of ticks on x and y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting an ellipse, which could become a circle if the values of the major and minor axis are the same. Therefore, I would like to have a square shape plot with the same number of ticks on the x and y-axes. I am already compting the maximum range for ticks in my program but still, the plot is not square-shaped as shown below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Step 1: Set the variables
groundtruth_position = (0, 0)
groundtruth_sigma_x = 1
groundtruth_sigma_y = 2

# Use the maximum value between groundtruth_sigma_x and groundtruth_sigma_y to decide the ticks
max_sigma = max(groundtruth_sigma_x, groundtruth_sigma_y)

# Calculate the tick range for both axes
tick_range = max_sigma * 1.5

# Step 2: Create a figure and plot the groundtruth_position as a single point in black color
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(*groundtruth_position, color='black')

# Step 3: Set custom ticks for both axes
x_ticks = np.arange(groundtruth_position[0] - tick_range, groundtruth_position[0] + tick_range + 1)
y_ticks = np.arange(groundtruth_position[1] - tick_range, groundtruth_position[1] + tick_range + 1)

# Set the ticks on the plot
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks)
ax.set_yticks(y_ticks)

# Ensure the aspect ratio is equal to make the plot square-shaped
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# Create an ellipse using groundtruth_sigma_x and groundtruth_sigma_y
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
x = groundtruth_sigma_x * np.cos(theta) + groundtruth_position[0]
y = groundtruth_sigma_y * np.sin(theta) + groundtruth_position[1]
ax.plot(x, y)

# Display the plot
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


print()
```

[image]

How can I have the same range on the x-axis (i.e. from -2 to 2) to make the plot square-shaped?

Comment: Have a look at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim, https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim, https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.update_datalim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.update_datalim

Comment: `ax.set(xlim=(-2, 2))` or better `ax.set(xlim=ax.get_ylim())` which results in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI2wI.png)

Comment: Also `ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Ah, it is `x` over `y`: `ax.set_aspect(aspect=groundtruth_sigma_x/groundtruth_sigma_y, adjustable='box')` [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html)